# Why can't Soap connect to HTTPS?

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap, ssl, https

I am trying to connect to a HTTPS `location`. Currently I get `Could not connect to host` error. I am testing on two Ubuntu servers. This error occurs on one Ubuntu server which is off site. The other server which is on a development server on site works fine. I searched the server files and have yet to find any differences in the systems that would cause this kind of issue.  I have yet to find someone with a similar issue and tried many different solutions related to the same error message (e.g. disabling wsdl caching, etc...).

- HTTP works fine on both servers
- HTTPS works on one server
- php.ini files are the same
- OpenSSL and Soap shows enabled in `phpinfo();` (HTTP works, so I assume Soap is fine)
- `wget https://exampleurl.com/services/SessionService` works fine on the server getting the error

What should I look at next?

What testing can I do?

How can I get addition info about the error?

```
$sessionService = new SessionService('/path/to/local/file/SessionService.wsdl', array(
          'location' => "https://exampleurl.com/services/SessionService"
      ));

try {
    // throws SoapFault error   
    $token = @Login($sessionService, $username, $password);
}
catch (SoapFault $sf) {
    //echo $sf->getMessage());
    //echo $sf;
}
```

SessionService class:

```
class SessionService extends SoapClient {

    private static $classmap = array(
        'login' => 'login',
        'loginResponse' => 'loginResponse',
        ...
    );

    public function SessionService($wsdl = "http://localhost:8080/services/SessionService?wsdl", $options = array()) {
        foreach (self::$classmap as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($options['classmap'][$key])) {
                $options['classmap'][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }


    //fails here
    public function login(login $parameters) {
        return $this->__soapCall('login', array($parameters), array(
            'uri' => 'http://example.url.com',
            'soapaction' => ''
            )
        );
    }

    //... other functions

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or a similar tool may be your best bet here, to understand what's going wrong with the http request(s). You're not going to be able to debug the actual http request from the client code in PHP as that's all in the SOAP extension (written in C).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the openssl extension enabled in php.ini.

```
;for windows
extension=php_openssl.dll 
;for unix 
extension=openssl.so
```